# Hide keyboard by touching the screen

Tags: ios, uiview, keyboard, uitouch

I want to hide the keyboard by touching the view. Everybody recommends to use this method, saying there's no need to link or anything else, but is not working.

The problem is that my method is not called.Is there anything else that should be done?

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had trouble with this so use a method that loops through all views seeing  if they are textviews and firstResponders. Not sure of the structure of a UITextView but you might need to check for that too although it may be covered.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView *txt in self.view.subviews){
        if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [txt isFirstResponder]) {
            [txt resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is not called. That is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to create a "lock view" which is a UIView that takes over the whole screen once the textField becomesFirstResponder. Make sure it's on top of all views (well, besides the textview, of course).

```
- (void)loadLockView {
    CGRect bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    _lockView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    _lockView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lockViewTapped:)];
    [_lockView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
    [self.view addSubview:_lockView];
}

- (void)lockViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tgr {
     [_lockView removeFromSuperView];
     [_textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UITapGestureRecognizer For Dismiss keyboard.

Write this code on your viewdidload().

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and in dismissKeyboard method put this code.

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [TextFieldName resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: You would have to specify each UITextField this way, a more generic approach would be better.